# SCSS stop keyframe SVG circle animation based on percentage

Tags: html, css, svg, sass, css-animations

Just created my first keyframe progression indicator, I am using it in my react project. I want to push a percentage state to this keyframe so I can fill the percentage to a certain point. For now, it fills but I don't understand how I can stop the animation. For example, I want the filler to stop at 50% when I push a prop with '50'.

[JSfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/d2cam8pg/)

```
<svg height="180" width="180" class="circle--static">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="71" stroke="#cde9db" stroke-width="6" fill-opacity="0" />
</svg>
<svg height="180" width="180" class="circle--animated">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="71" stroke="#68c087" stroke-width="10" fill-opacity="0" />
</svg>
```

```
.circle--static {
      circle {
         stroke-dasharray: 4;
         animation: stroke 2s ease-out forwards;
       }
   }

   .circle--animated {
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;

      circle {
         stroke-dasharray: 1000;
         stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
         animation: stroke 60s ease-out forwards;
         animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      }

      @keyframes stroke {
         to {
            stroke-dashoffset: 0;
         }
      }

      @keyframes fadeIn {
         to {
            opacity: 1;
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total length of a path in SVG can be found using the [getTotalLength](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement/getTotalLength) method. In your case you could also use the formula for the perimeter of a circle (2*Math.PI*r).

Anyway you need to know the length of the path you want to animate which in this case is 445.

```
stroke-dasharray: 445;
stroke-dashoffset: 445;
```

If you want to stop the animation at 50% this means you have to stop it at `445 / 2 = 222.5`

```
 @keyframes stroke {
      to {
        stroke-dashoffset: 222.5;
      }
    }
```

Next come the demo. I hope it helps.

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.circle--static circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 4;
  animation: stroke 2s ease-out forwards;
}

.circle--animated {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}
.circle--animated circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 445;
  stroke-dashoffset: 445;
  animation: stroke 6s ease-out forwards;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes stroke {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 222.5;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeIn {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg height="180" width="180" class="circle--static">
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="71" stroke="#cde9db" stroke-width="6" fill-opacity="0" />
</svg>


<svg height="180" width="180" class="circle--animated">
  <circle id="kk" cx="100" cy="100" r="71" stroke="#68c087" stroke-width="10" fill-opacity="0" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, great explanation! :)

Comment: Just a small additional question, by what attribute can we change the starting point of the animation as it should start at the top (0%) and not at 25% :)

Comment: In this case you may want to rotate the svg canvas or consider using a `<path>` instead of a circle.